# Simple server/client GUI Communication

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an application setup in this manner:

The server listens for a incoming connection from the client, and when the client connects, both the server and the client spawn a new thread monitoring any changes in the GUI (button click, command, etc..). My problem is how can I get the server and client threads to communicate with each other (report any changes in their respective GUI states)? I've been searching for answer for days now but can't seem to find one. Bear in mind I just started learning concurrency so please be as detailed as possible with your response.

Comment: I assume that the server and client are in different processes... how far have you got in terms of the network side of things? It's not really clear whether your question is about threading or inter-process communication.

Comment: The server and client are in different processes and have their respective threads when they connect. The purpose of the threads is to monitor any changes in their GUI and report. Let's say the client clicks on a button, i need some way to notify the server thread(which is running on a different computer) that the client clicked a button, and update the server GUI in some way, and vice versa. So I also need a way to get the clients GUI from the server's end, and the server's GUI from the client's end as well.

Comment: @user862806: Did you already make a decision on the protocol to use, e.g. sockets: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html?

Comment: @user862806: Usually you can only access GUI elements from the GUI threads themselves - so you probably want the GUI thread to listen for changes, but then queue the notification of those changes to be sent to the server. You should probably think about the communications side of things next, rather than threading.

Comment: Yes im using the client/server model with sockets

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Thanks for your response, but I have no clue where to start, would you suggest I use something like the RMI model or JavaSpace? I'm thinking that will be an overkill for what i'm trying to accomplish.. maybe i'm wrong?

Comment: @user862806: I wouldn't go for something like RMI, personally. Your choice of network protocol partly depends on requirements - do you need your server/client to operate through a firewall? If so, you'll almost certainly want to use HTTP.

Comment: How would i be able to update the GUI's then? All i can do is open the sockets input/output streams and write/receive text to and fro

Answer (score 0):

You can use network protocol to communicate between server and client such as HTTP (quite common).

For the message passing between client and server, there are different types of protocol, such as XML, JSON or a light-weighted Protocol Buffer, etc.

You can define your own definition on XML , JSON and use your own definition to trigger action you want between both.

A good client-server architecture should not depend on specific language you use, such as Java. The client should adopt different programming languages that receive message from server side.

Comment: thanks, but how exactly would i incorporate XML into all this? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Any time an event occurs, you need to create some sort of "event" object, encode it, and send that over the network to the other process, which then receives it, decodes it, and executes the same event.

As far as being able to send the event object over the network, you need a way of encoding and decoding it as a string/bytes. For this you have a few options - for pre-implemented methods, you could try the java Serializable/ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream, or the XMLEncoder/XMLDecoder. You might also look into other XML or JSON libraries, or even writing your own encoder/decoder if the events are simple enough.